# NoSuchMethodError (NoSuchMethodError: The method 'asset' was called on null

Tags: flutter

[image]

NoSuchMethodError (NoSuchMethodError: The method 'asset' was called on null.

Comment: assets:
    - assets/images/logo.jpg

Comment: Try `Image` with a capital I.

Answer (score 1):

You have declared "image" as a getter and set it too null. So, might consider changing that or using "Image" with capital "I" which is a flutter widget if you are trying to use that then it's a spelling error.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
in pubspec.yml

add this
flutter:
  uses-material-design: true,
  assets:
    - images/
```